# Magento2 Enable WYSIWYG On Email Templates Admin Panel

Tags: magento2.3, email, wysiwyg

I know Magento has a WYSIWYG library but I am surprised that when you go to Marketing>Email Templates and click into one of the email templates the textarea is not WYSIWYG enabled.

Does anyone know what fileI would edit or an open source plugin that would enable that textarea to be a WYSIWYG